# Transform a CSV of Ids into a CSV of Names

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I need to transform a csv of Ids into a csv of Names.
I have:

```
FOLDER ID NAME  |  FILE  ID NAME PATH
       1  A              1  fX   1
       2  AB             2  fZ   1,2
       3  B              3  fY   3,4
       4  BC             4  fW   3,4,5
       5  BCD
```

Get info about FILEs and its sizes from the FILEDATA table

```
select FILE.NAME, FILE.PATH, FILEDATA.SIZE
from FILEDATA inner join FILE on FILEDATA.fileid = FILE.id 
WHERE FILEDATA.PropName = "Size"
```

Actually I get

```
fX  1      23805
fZ  1,2    27205
fY  3,4    23608
fW  3,4,5  21501
```

I need replace the IDs by the FOLDER names

```
fX  A         23805
fZ  A/AB      27205
fY  B/BC      23608
fW  B/BC/BDC  21501
```

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, is not me who store:)

Comment: @jarlh materialized paths might be the exception

Comment: Best solution - use programming language, like python. If not for the necessity to include subparts like B/BC/BDC in your example, you could get away with FIND_IN_SET in a join condition, but you can't because of the subparts exactly.